# Data Toggle with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a tabular structure in my page with each row being present in ng-repeat. I also have a `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#status0"` property on click of a button. These buttons are also part of the ng-repeat div. The problem am facing is if I click on the button, in say 3rd row, 4th column, it still shows the collapsible div in the first row 4th column. That is the collapsible divs are always coming in the first row. Am unable to debug how to get this working.

My html code looks like this :

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in groups">
            <tr>
            <td rowspan="{{group.rowLength}}" ng-hide="$index>=0"></td>

            <td>{{group.serviceName}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class={{group.colorMe[0]}}>{{group.env1}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-controller="group.funcName" ng-click="sanity( group.serviceName , 'env1', group.colorMe[0], group.id)">Sanity</button>
                <button ng-class= "{'success':group.testsRun[0]==='Success', 'progress':group.testsRun[0]!='Success' && group.testsRun[0]!='failed', 'failed':group.testsRun[0]==='failed'}" ng-show="group.clicked[0]" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#status0">{{group.testsRun[0]}}</button>
                <div id="status0" class="collapse">
                    <p background-color: "#39D1B4" color: "#fff">
                        The tests which failed are : {{group.showResults[0]}}.
                        For more info, visit <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class={{group.colorMe[1]}}>{{group.env2}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-controller="group.funcName" ng-click="sanity( group.serviceName , 'env2', group.colorMe[1], group.id)">Sanity</button>
                <button ng-class= "{'success':group.testsRun[1]==='Success', 'progress':group.testsRun[1]!='Success' && group.testsRun[1]!='failed', 'failed':group.testsRun[1]==='failed'}" ng-show="group.clicked[1]" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#status1">{{group.testsRun[1]}}</button>
                <div id="status1" class="collapse">
                    <p background-color: "#39D1B4" color: "#fff">The tests which failed are : {{group.showResults[1]}}. For more info, visit <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class={{group.colorMe[2]}}>{{group.env3}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-controller="group.funcName" ng-click="sanity( group.serviceName , 'env3', group.colorMe[2], group.id)">Sanity</button>
                <button ng-class= "{'success':group.testsRun[2]==='Success', 'progress':group.testsRun[2]!='Success' && group.testsRun[2]!='failed', 'failed':group.testsRun[2]==='failed'}" ng-show="group.clicked[2]" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#status2">{{group.testsRun[2]}}</button>
                <div id="status2" class="collapse">
                    <p background-color: "#39D1B4" color: "#fff">The tests which failed are : {{group.showResults[2]}}. For more info, visit <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class={{group.colorMe[3]}}>{{group.env4}}</div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-controller="group.funcName" ng-click="sanity( group.serviceName , 'env4', group.colorMe[3], group.id)">Sanity</button>
                <button ng-class= "{'success':group.testsRun[3]==='Success', 'progress':group.testsRun[3]!='Success' && group.testsRun[3]!='failed', 'failed':group.testsRun[3]==='failed'}" ng-show="group.clicked[3]" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#status3">{{group.testsRun[3]}}</button>
                <div id="status3" class="collapse">
                    <p background-color: "#39D1B4" color: "#fff">The tests which failed are : {{group.showResults[3]}}. For more info, visit <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
                </div>
            </td>
```

The $scope.groups looks like this:

```
$scope.groups=[];
    var services = [ser1, ser2, ser3, ser4];
    $scope.indexes = {"env1" : 0, "env2" : 1, "env3" : 2, "env4": 3};
    $scope.funcNames = [func1, func2, func3, func4];
    for(i=0;i<services.length;i++)
    {
        var group = {
            "id": i,
            "rowLength": 7,//check
            "funcName": $scope.funcNames[i],
            "clicked": [false, false, false, false],
            "showResults": ["", "", "", ""],
            "showLogs": ["", "", "", "",],
            "testsRun": ["notStarted", "notStarted", "notStarted", "notStarted"],
            "serviceName":services[i].toUpperCase(),
            "ENV1":versionMap["env1"+services[i]],
            "ENV2":versionMap["env2"+services[i]],
            "ENV3":versionMap["env3"+services[i]],
            "ENV4":versionMap["env4"+services[i]]
        };
        $scope.groups.push(group);
    }//end of for loop
```

Please guide as to what am doing wrong.

Comment: show `$scope.groups` also

Comment: can you create fiddler? @tarun

Comment: For starters, don't you think you have placed `ng-repeat` in the wrong element?

Comment: @Tarun your id must be different for each case..

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal - I have updated the code with groups variable.

Comment: @Jenny - Will do it asap. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Sagar - I did not get you? Can you please explain.

Comment: @SahilDhir - You mean it should be data-target="#status22" data-target="#status23" instead of data-target="#status2" everytime. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just saying. shouldn't your `ng-repeat` be on `tr` element instead of `tbody`

Comment: tarun. Please check the code I have posted as answer. It will solve your errors. In case it doesnt let me know. If in case it does, please do mark it as correct

Comment: @Sagar - No, thats how the data has been modelled. I think this way it would be more helpful to my requirements this way. Thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found your error.

You are repeating dom id's which is messing up your codes. it has to be unique. You can try to add group id to it if you have.

```
<!-- id cannot be same for any two doms -->
<div id="status0{{group.id}}" class="collapse">
   <p background-color: "#39D1B4" color: "#fff">
        The tests which failed are : {{group.showResults[0]}}.
        For more info, visit <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>.
   </p>
</div>
```

Similarly you will have to change your button's target as well

```
<button ng-class= "{'success':group.testsRun[0]==='Success', 'progress':group.testsRun[0]!='Success' && group.testsRun[0]!='failed', 'failed':group.testsRun[0]==='failed'}" ng-show="group.clicked[0]" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#status0{{group.id}}">{{group.testsRun[0]}}</button>
```